# PHP $wpdb Select?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select

I could use some assistance with an sql query. I have a small 3 column table, id, ip, and birthday. id auto increments.

I'm trying to select all birthdays that are associated with a specific ip, but I'm not sure if the SQL statement I wrote is correct. The var_dump returns an empty array. If someone could check this for me it would be appreciated.

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT birthday FROM $table WHERE ip=$ip";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Do an `echo $query;` and add that to your question

Comment: @Machavity I just tested echo $query. The correct table name and a valid ip found in the table was echo'd.

Comment: Is it as simple as missing single quotes around the IP? i.e. `WHERE ip='$ip'`

Comment: @nickyb Just humor me here. I'm not asking just for idle curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap ip address passed to mysql with `single quotes`, use actual table name. if your resulting array is blank, then you are missing that ip from your table.

Comment: I'm using wordpress so I just called the global inside the function I'm writing making the call. `global $wpdb;` I've used this before without any problems, but I've always used `get_row` to fetch a single row. The function is written in functions.php.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion gets parsed exactly the same as what I already have. I just embedded the variables in double quotes instead of concatenating.

Comment: can you paste here what your final string looks like value-wise, and describe what is happening or not. also explain your error handling

Comment: I don't want to paste my table name or ip, but that's what gets parsed. So the correct table name and my ip which can be found in the table is passed through as SQL. So $results should be an array of all the birthdays selected in the table associated with my IP. `$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);` The var_dump should show all the birthdays I have in the table with my IP as ip, which at the moment is 8 in total. But instead of dumping an array with 8 dates, $results is empty.

Comment: update to answer, in fact i clobbered old one, sorry to slow u down.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and help out, but it's still empty. If the $query statement is correct, there must be a problem with $results.

Comment: the top part of the rewrite does not use an array, the second one puts it together differently than yours, so i am looking at my code (the thingies array)

Comment: I just tested your second block of code and still no dice. `ARRAY_A` will set $results as an associative array.

Comment: then my conclusion, there are no results at all for that ip address ! Sometimes i need some sniffing salts

Comment: the whole concept is funny. i identify the user by ipaddress and get their birthday !

Comment: i actually replaced my variables with the table name and ip string and still empty array. It's all part of a much larger function, it's just checking if the date needs to be written into the database if it hasn't already by that person. Not meant to identify a person for any other reason.

Comment: so you have a data problem/assumption, not a code problem, ipaddress is not found using the select stmt, you are saying, i think

Comment: That's likely, but i'm not sure why. I've checked several times for typos. ip is called "ip" and is a varchar(20), birthday is called "birthday" and is a int(8). And I can insert to the table without any problems from my function.

Comment: but what does the data in db show compared to the value in your select stmt. cuz u wouldn't show actual select stmt i am flying blind as usual

Comment: Example: (id | ip | bithday) as (1 | 123.456.789.0 | 01011900 )

Comment: so if you dump out $query it says, and being exact is important with quotes and single quotes, make it up and paste it here. make up the ipaddr just paste the whole thing here

Comment: let me rephrase. $query. we know $results is array {}. we are trying to make that not be {}

Comment: what does $query say when you dump it. (make up a diff ipaddr)

Comment: i know exactly what the problem is, i just can't get the $query out of you

Comment: `string(54) “SELECT birthday FROM my_table WHERE ip=my_ip″` this is the result of the query dump. I've replaced "my_table" and "my_ip" both were the correct values.

Comment: ok, so you need to wrap my_ip with single quotes, which was my original answer way back when. and if that returns an empty array, then that ipaddr ain't in your db

Comment: that's exactly what i did except w/o numbers: `string(54) “SELECT birthday FROM my_table WHERE ip=11.11.1.111″`

Comment: “SELECT birthday FROM my_table WHERE ip= '11.11.1.111'    ″